# Prove that $n=O(n\log n)$ using the definition

Tags: limits, computer-science

The definition:
given two functions $f$ and $g$, $f(n)$ is in the class $O(g(n))$ if there exist constants $N$ and $c$ such that $f(n)<c ⋅ g(n)$ when $n > N$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prove $n$ is $O(n\log n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890897/prove-n-is-on-log-n)

Comment: @Rohan The question writer of the linked question asked for help when proving this by *limits*.  Here, OP asks for a proof using the *definition*, so IMHO, it's not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

> When $N\ge3$, for all $n\ge N$, $\log n\ge\log N >1$, so $n < n \log n$ whenever $n > N$.

Comment: Can you write how did you get $3$?

Comment: $\log N>1 \iff N > e \Leftarrow N \ge \lfloor e \rfloor + 1$